# How to match & align columns A & B with C& D

Tags: excel, alignment, match, multiple-columns

I want to match up my clients in column A & C along with their corresponding balances in B & D. Columns A & B are my receivables from last month. C & D are this month. I want to compare each client on the same row, side by side.

```
 A        B          C           D
Jane    100.00      Jim        50.00
Jim      10.00      Carl      200.00
Bryan   210.00      Curtis     50.00
Carl     50.00      Dane       50.00
Dane      0.00      Doris     100.00
```

Desired result:

---

```
 A        B          C           D
Jane    100.00      
Jim      10.00      Jim        50.00
Bryan   210.00      
Carl     50.00      Carl      200.00
                    Curtis     50.00
Dane      0.00      Dane       50.00
                    Doris     100.00
```

Comment: @hoss much appreciated for the edit.

Comment: do you have any code or errors you are running into

Comment: Can't come up with a formula that works. I can match up A with C, but not along with their balances.

Comment: What language are you using? How are you populating these columns? Where does your data come from?

Comment: I think this question is more suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) as it's not about programming per se.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I've tried all suggestions but not quite there yet. I've updated main post to show my desired output. Hope that explains better.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this just with Excel functions, you can get the comparison values where the names match in both months like this:

```
 A        B         E
Jane    100.00       #N/A
Jim      10.00      50.00
Bryan   210.00       #N/A
Carl     50.00     200.00
Dane      0.00      50.00
```

That is for cell E1. You need to copy down and hide columns C & D to get the above output.

```
=INDEX(D:D, MATCH(A1,$C:$C, 0), 1)
```

Of course, this is not a complete solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want this:
[image]

Then

type `=CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2)` in `F2`,

type `=CONCATENATE(C2," ",D2)` in `G2`,

type `=OFFSET(F2,0,1)` in `F10`.

DONE!